# Check if dropbox is responding Reachability iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, dropbox

I am using dropbox to upload and download shared files from the dropbox account. this means that every user is able to download the latest version of the file, modify it, and re-upload it, substituting the one before. If there is a stable internet connection, this process works, but if the internet is not responding, the file will be corrupted, and a version of the file that is not complete will be uploaded. This will damage all the users. Is there a way to check if there is a stable internet connection with the dropbox servers? I tried reachability, but it only controls internet connection, not dropbox servers responding.

The code for the error:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {
NSLog(@"File upload failed with error - %@", error);

UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Offline mode" message:@"Your event is going to be posted when you create a new event." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert1 show];

 }
```

The point is that even if this function is called, the file is still uploaded on the internet!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: or at least restore the previous version of the file

Comment: yes you can load the previous version of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if your account is linked with dropbox use this .`[[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]` that returns a `BOOL` value

```
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {         
       // write your code here..
   }
```

and then to restore your file to previous version ..

For that you just have to understand them clearly

1. you have to load the [revisions](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#revisions) of the file, that you are going to restore.
   for that you can use either one of these method

***Obtains [metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#metadata) for the previous revisions of a file.
Only revisions up to thirty days old are available.***

```
/* Loads a list of up to 10 DBMetadata objects representing past revisions of the file at path */
- (void)loadRevisionsForFile:(NSString *)path;

/* Same as above but with a configurable limit to number of DBMetadata objects returned, up to 1000 */
- (void)loadRevisionsForFile:(NSString *)path limit:(NSInteger)limit;
```

for example :
                    [[self restClient] loadRevisionsForFile:@"YourFile" limit:10];

and these delegate methods from where you can get the array of revisions values for your file

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedRevisions:(NSArray *)revisions forFile:(NSString *)path;
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadRevisionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

for example:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedRevisions:(NSArray *)revisions forFile:(NSString *)path {

    NSArray  *dbRevisionsArray = revisions;
}
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadRevisionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error{

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!!!" message:@"Please try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

So now you have array of metadata of previous revisions of your file.

1. To restore the file ***[[About Restore]](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#restore)***,

> Here there are two cases:
>
> Case 1: is to restore the file in Dropbox
>   (*here you have restored the file only in the Dropbox, to have your restored file  in your APP, you have to load the file again to you Database as usual*)
>
> Case 2: is to restore the file in your DataBase (*here You can restore your
>   file only in App's Database but not in Dropbox, To restore in Dropbox follow Case 1: *)

**Case 1: *Restore the file in Dropbox***

// Restores a file at path as it existed at the given rev and returns the metadata of     the restored file after restoration

```
 - (void)restoreFile:(NSString *)path toRev:(NSString *)rev;
```

// and their delegate methods

```
 - (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client restoredFile:(DBMetadata *)fileMetadata;
 - (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client restoreFileFailedWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

for example:

```
       DBMetadata *metaData = [dbRevisionsArray objectAtIndex:row];
      NSString *revStr = metaData.rev;
[[self restClient] restoreFile:@"yourFilePath" toRev:revStr];
```

then Load the file to your database path..

that's it ,.

**Case 2: *Restore file only in App's Database (Not in Dropbox)***

/* This will load a file as it existed at a given rev */

```
- (void)loadFile:(NSString *)path atRev:(NSString *)rev intoPath:(NSString *)destPath;

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)destPath contentType:(NSString*)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata;
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error;
```

for example:     `[[self restClient] loadFile:@"yourFile" atRev:revStr intoPath:toYourDatabasePath];`

Comment: Great answer, but what's the difference between: restoreFle...toRev, and loadRevisionForFile...limit10 ? What is the limit 10? Which one shall I use, supposing I want to restore a previous version of the file from dropbox? Just like restoring a file from the back up disk?

Comment: - (void)restoreFile:(NSString *)path toRev:(NSString *)rev; is a method that restores the dropbox File at a given revision , for example let me create a file in Dropbox named "Contacts" with revision as cont1, lets consider that i have updated my Contacts file in Dropbox, so its current revision would be changed as cont2, and now if you need to restore back 1st revision in Dropbox, you i have to call this `[[self restClient] restoreFile:@"Contacts" toRev:@"cont1"]`; , when it is over, Contacts file will be restored to its previous version

Comment: limit to number of DBMetadata objects returned, up to 1000 
- (void)loadRevisionsForFile:(NSString *)path limit:(NSInteger)limit; this method returns the revisions of file, for example [[self restClient] loadRevisionsForFile:@"Contacts" limit:10]; this will return me a 10 DBMetadata objects from which we can get the revisions and then we can restore using the revision string

Comment: Ok thanks. One last thig: when I upload a file to dropbox I use: [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir  fromPath:tmpPngName]; , without withParentRev:nil, since I want to replace completely the file. in this case can I still use RestoreFile...toRev??

Comment: So, I am trying restoreFile...toRev, what do I need to put for toRev? Since when I have uploaded it I used withParentRev: nil?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20810/discussion-between-bala-and-alessandro)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Reachability to check for a specific host: `reachabilityWithHostName:`

```
@implementation DDViewController {
    Reachability *r;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    if(!r) {
        r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"dropbox.com"];
        [r startNotifier];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
    }
}

- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSLog(@"%@", note);
    self.view.backgroundColor = [note.object isReachable]?[UIColor greenColor] : [UIColor redColor];
}
```

--TODO: get the real hostname used by the DBRestClient--

Comment: Where can I find the real hostname used by the DB...? Because I aready use rechability and as website I used "www.dropbox.com", but that doesn't really work

Comment: ah so THAT's the real question ^^ -- dont know the api though